# Can I receive an email notification from Yahoo Messenger when I am offline?

Tags: email, notifications, yahoo-messenger

I use Yahoo Messenger for communication with a few people, but there are large blocks of time when I am not signed in since messages during those times are not likely - e.g., during the weekends.

But I always have email available to me. Is it possible to setup Yahoo Messenger to send a notification by email if someone sends me an instant message when I am not signed into Messenger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible for either forward your Yahoo! Messenger IMs to an email address nor is it possible to have them notify you via email that an IM has arrived.

What you can do, as an alternative, is use [Yahoo Messenger via SMS](http://mobile.yahoo.com/messenger/sms) to interact with your contacts in those off periods.